# Kafka Kerberos - Broker only

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos

I am trying to configure Kafka brokers for inter-broker kerberos only. However, I seem to keep coming across errors due to the fact it seems to want to connect to Zookeepers via Kerberos as well. I have not yet setup any Zookeeper keytabs at the moment.

My Kafka broker JAAS config is as follows:

```
    KafkaServer {


    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    serviceName=kafkabroker
    keytab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_server.keytab"
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    principal="kafkabroker/kafkabroker0.domain.name@REALM.COM";


    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="user"
    password="secret"
    user_admin="admin"
    user_alice="secret";
};

Client {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="secret";
};
```

server.properties

```
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN, GSSAPI
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafkabroker
```

The error I get with the above configuration is below:

```
    [2019-02-08 10:08:17,995] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.createSaslToken(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:279)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.respondToServer(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:242)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:805)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:94)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1145)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,015] ERROR [ZooKeeperClient] Auth failed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,048] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$AuthFailedException: KeeperErrorCode = AuthFailed for /consumers
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:126)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
        at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:499)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1456)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.makeSurePersistentPathExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1378)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1370)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1370)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createTopLevelPaths(KafkaZkClient.scala:1370)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:373)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:202)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.startup(SupportedServerStartable.java:114)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:66)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,056] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,058] WARN  (kafka.utils.CoreUtils$)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$shutdown$5.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaServer.scala:579)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.swallow(CoreUtils.scala:86)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:579)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:329)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.startup(SupportedServerStartable.java:114)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:66)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,060] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,063] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,065] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,065] INFO Shutting down SupportedServerStartable (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,065] INFO Shutting down KafkaServer (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable)
[2019-02-08 10:08:18,065] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

In other words, I only want kerberos for broker-to-broker and PLAIN SASL_SSL for Broker - Zookeeper. Is that even possible?

Comment: You'll need Zookeeper kerberized as well, first - https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_gssapi.html

Comment: Ok so I managed to get this working. I changed the server.properties to be:
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI

And in the server_jaas.conf I only had the KafkaServer block with krb5LoginModule sub block.

Answer (score 1):

So, I managed to get this working. I needed to update my /etc/krb5.conf file with the "default_realm" and "[realms]" details.

Then I changed the server_jaas.conf file as follows:

```
KafkaServer {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    serviceName=kafkabroker
    keytab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_server.keytab"
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    principal="kaffka_service_account@REALM";
}
```

Finally I updated my server.properties file as follows:

```
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafkabroker
```